# Remove the placeholder image from the developer story if I have no image set

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, profile-picture

The developer story (the one at the `https://stackoverflow.com/story/(name)` URL) has this quite big placeholder image at the top of my CV because I don't have an image set for it:

[image: a default boring sort of head-and-shoulders silhouette]

If I don't have an image set, please just don't show it at all. There shouldn't be a placeholder image: just an image (if I've added one), or nothing. It looks fine without the placeholder, too.

In the two regions in which I have lived or worked (London and Australia) CVs *do not contain photos.* In Australia a photo on your CV is one of the fastest ways to get your CV put in a bin, because that's the safest way for recruitment to handle anti-discrimination laws. London similarly seems to avoid them.

So whilst a placeholder like this usually suggests “they haven't put something here yet,” I'm going to put something there *never* and it's not expected by anyone I'll do anything different. Effectively the placeholder would be a permanent feature of my Stack Overflow CV, but that shouldn't be the case.

Both the CV and the Developer Story look fine with just omitting that image outright if there's nothing to put there. (By contrast, having the placeholder is a bit unsightly.) It's more “correct” to not have it there at all from the perspective of my hiring region. If I opt not to have an image, I'd like my developer story & CV views to correspondingly just omit any hint there ought to be one.

Comment: In my experience, in the Netherlands, you always add a picture to your CV. Potential employers usually appreciate that. That said, if no image is uploaded, a placeholder is kinda silly.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's fine. :) I don't want the image to be removed completely, there's definitely regions in which it's a great feature -- but I just want the image placeholder to not be there if I *don't* have an image added.

Comment: I can't say I've ever seen an image on a CV before in my life, albeit I'm also in the UK